# Can I get loaded pdb file path from IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

IDA Pro can automatically download and load `.pdb` files from symbol server.
And now I want to write an IDAPython plugin to obtain some data from the `.pdb` file.

But I don't know how to get the file path of the already loaded `.pdb` file.
Can I get it using IDAPython?

Comment: iirc the pdb file name is printed in the header information scroll to the top and look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just checked idafree 76 and i dont see an idc function to get the pdb file name
but as i commented it is printed in the header you can copy paste it

```
.text:0000000140001000 ; Alignment     : default
.text:0000000140001000 ; PDB File Name : C:\xx\Desktop\mulcall\mcall.pdb
```

or you can search text for string(".pdb") path is normally available in **.rdata** section IMAGE_DEBUG_DIRECTORY

using idc function like as below

```
auto cline;
cline = find_text(MinEA()+0x1000,1,0,0,".PDB");
jumpto(cline);
Message("%x\t%s\n" , cline , get_curline());
```

which should yield

```
14000206c .rdata:000000014000206C text "UTF-8",'C:\xxx\Desktop\mulcall\mcall.pdb',0 ; PdbFileName
```

be aware this is from debug directory and may not be correct in malwares , stripped , public , etc , manipulated binaries

for example a public pdb might return

```
1802420f0   .rdata:00000001802420F0   text "UTF-8", 'kernelbase.pdb',0 ; PdbFileName
```

in such cases like public pdbs of ms binaries best option is to use
dumpbin /pdbpath

```
dumpbin /pdbpath c:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll

Dump of file c:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll

File Type: DLL
  PDB file found at 'f:\symbols\kernelbase.pdb\993F0EEA8C3C260F6D52724A7CA166601\kernelbase.pdb'
```

Comment: It's a good idea